# Does the Schrödinger equation take vacuum energy into account?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, vacuum, cosmological-constant

As I understand it (and excuse me if I get it wrong or partially wrong), the Schrödinger equation is an energy equation that states that the energy of a quantum system stays constant in time.

So how does it account for vacuum energy?
If it doesn't, how do physicists calculate the evolution of quantum systems while taking into account vacuum energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schrödinger equation is part of Quantum Mechanics (QM). The vacuum energy is something which pops up in Quantum Field Theory (QFT). QFT is an extension of QM which incorporates special relativity and which makes it natural to create/destroy particles. Technically QFT is a part of QM but it brings so much more to the table that I don't feel bad calling it an extension.

In QM the number of particles is fixed. You can model any number of particles that you want but this number stays the same over time. In QM you *could* model a vacuum state with zero particles but it would be very boring. It would just be an empty state for all time. In QFT the number of particles can fluctuate and here the vacuum state is very important. The vacuum state is like a blank canvas on which you can paint particles. It also has an energy associated with it and fluctuations as well.

So to answer your question the Schrödinger equation from QM doesn't take into account vacuum energy. To see the vacuum energy you would have to look at the Schrödinger equation equivalent in a QFT.

Comment: "Technically QFT is a part of QM but it brings so much more to the table that I don't feel bad calling it an extension" - Could you eloborate please? This sounds weird, since the first statement seems to be the exact opposite of the second one.

Comment: @Filippo QFT can be derived entirely using QM (I'm not 100% sure on that but fairly sure) so technically QFT would be a subset of QM. But the framework of QFT is so extensive that you could call it an extension of QM. Likewise Lagrangian/Hamiltonian mechanics are a subset of Newtonian mechanics but in a loose sense you could call them an extension of Newtonian mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your comment:

> "Technically QFT is a part of QM but it brings so much more to the table that I don't feel bad calling it an extension" - Could you eloborate please? This sounds weird, since the first statement seems to be the exact opposite of the second one.

This old  [wikipedia introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(physics)) said it in a nutshell

> In physics, quantization (quantisation) is the process of transition from a classical understanding of physical phenomena to a newer understanding known as quantum mechanics. (It is a procedure for constructing a quantum field theory starting from a classical field theory.) This is a generalization of the procedure for building quantum mechanics from classical mechanics. Also related is field quantization, as in the "quantization of the electromagnetic field", referring to photons as field "quanta" (for instance as light quanta). *This procedure is basic to theories of particle physics, nuclear physics, condensed matter physics, and quantum optics*

italics mine

Given a quantum mechanical differential wave equation a quantum field theory can be built .

The Schrodinger equation was the first wave equation that succeeded in describing data (the hydrogen atom spectrum) rigorously. For particle physics it was superseded by the Klein Gordon for bosons, the Dirac for fermions, the quantized Maxwell for photons ....

Quantum field theory for particle physics is built up by using the plane wave solutions of the corresponding to the particles equations to model  the particle  fields, on which field creation and annihilation operators create and destroy particles , used in the calculation of the Feynman diagrams of the many particle interactions. So particle QFT is based on the [quantum mechanics postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) , but is a mathematical meta level of calculation used for many particle states.  In that sense an extension.